# How to exclude `->` in PHP files?

Tags: php, regex

I'm having problem understanding Regular Expression. Here is what I've got

> $pat = "/<[^>]*>/";

This pattern works well in removing all the HTML tags. But when it's used to remove `<?php ?>` tags, it has problem when `->` exist in between the tag.

i.e

```
<?php
  $obj->name;
  $obj->reset();
?>
some other things outside
```

Intended result

```
some other things outside
```

The actual result

```
  name;
  $obj->reset();
?>
some other things outside
```

So, how can I exclude the `->` in my search?

Comment: Have you [tried a proper parser instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)? :)

Comment: You'll also have a problem with greater than, right shift, and strings containing '>'. Better use a parser ;)

Comment: hmm.. never heard of the parser yet. Will try that out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either code in a special exception for the `<?php ?>` delimiters, so it takes precedence over the generic rule:

```
$pat = "/<[?].*?[?]>|<[^>]*>/";
```

<s>Or you use an assertion `(?=...)` and allow `->` as alternative</s>. Wah no, that's probably too difficult.

Comment: it doesn't seems to work .. hmm I think I'll just go for the parser. thanks!

Comment: Lacks the `/s` flag. And [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags) would have worked too, if that's what you actually wanted.